# What is the simplest way to handle django ORM access e.g <model>__<model>, select_related

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to implement a soft delete to model. The problem is that project is big and i need to find all filtering and access expressions to target model and edit it.

Is there a workaround to handle them on target model side?

Tried django-softdelete lib. The difficulties were that target table is a built-in django and target model is a proxy to it

Comment: Why not use a package like django-softdelete? This has a lot of logic w.r.t. to that.